# Strange behaviour UIButton in ios(Xamarin)

Tags: ios, xamarin, uiscrollview, xamarin.ios, xamarin-studio

I have `View` inside `ScrollView`. At end side my View I have submit `Button`. The Submit Button Constraint are below.

**Button Constraint :**

```
Top to superView : 630
Leading to superView : 40
```

**ScrollView Constraint :**

```
Top to superView : 0
Leading to superView : 0
Trainling to superView  : 0
Bottom to superView : 0
```

**View (That is inside my ScrollView) Constraint :**

```
Top to superView : 0
Leading to superView : 0
Trainling to superView  : 0
Bottom to superView : 0
```

When I set upper constraint the ScrollView is in normal behaviour means it can scroll top to bottom.

But I when Increase the width of `Button` means I want to set `Button` from both side 40 constraint. That time ScrollView doesn't scroll.

**After Change Button Constraint :**

```
Top to superView : 630
Leading to superView : 40
Traling to superView : 40
```

Why this happening I don't know ?

Any help be Appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried it and the following setup works for me fine:

Button Constraint :

```
Top to superView : 630
Leading to superView : 40
Trailing to superView : 40 (@750)
Bottom to superview: 0
```

ScrollView Constraint :

```
Top to Top Layout Guide : 0
Leading to superView : 0
Trainling to superView  : 0
Bottom to superView : 0
```

View (That is inside my ScrollView) Constraint :

```
Top to superView : 0
Leading to superView : 0
Trainling to superView  : 0
Bottom to superView : 0
Width : equal to superview
```

When you use scrollview an inner view requires all the constraints (top, leading, trailing, bottom). Otherwise scrollview is not able to calculate its content view.

Comment: wait i try to implement you answer and tell you soon.

Comment: Thanks for the Help. I try to make it last 2 days. Finally it work with your help.